# Place an imageView dynamically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

i am adding an imageView to a Relative layout.It shows up at the beginning of layout

I have two buttons in the layout.

I button to the layout left and one to layout right. Now i want to place these under the button to right.

how can i do that. My code is

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this); 
             image.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
             layout.addView(image);
```

[image: here is the image]

Comment: "Now i want to place these under the button to right." What is "these"? A screenshot might help to show what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the

> android:Layout_below="@id/yourButtonId" or
>   android:LayoutBelow="@id/yourButtonId"

Programmatically it means :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, yourButtonVariable.getId());
yourRelativeLayout.addView(yourImageView, rlp);
```

Comment: but my relative layout is already initialized. layout in above code is my relative layout

Comment: Here (with my code), you are not initializing your relative layout but your IMAGEVIEW...
What this snippet does is :
You add layoutparams to your image view in order to make it go BELOW a button

Comment: thanks i got it :) but now it is gone below the first button. I have two buttons, one is set to extreme left and other to extreme right. when i click extreme right button it should add a pic and show its thumbnail below the button. but it is showing under first one :)

Comment: Then just :
rlp.addRule(..., yourSecondButton.getId());

Comment: i am using rlp.addRule(receipt.getID) but it is showing like this

Comment: Just try :
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, receipt.getId());
This will just clip your view to the right of your RelativeLayout.

Comment: Aniway, the best way to do it would be to have your button in a LinearLayout with a vertical orientation si your image is directly below your button...